# Does an Edge require you to take a Hindrance?

Tags: savage-worlds

I'm looking at the [Savage Worlds Test Drive](http://www.peginc.com/Downloads/SWEX/TD06.pdf) and it provides a list of *Hindrances* and *Edges*.  Do I have to take an equivalent *Hindrance* for each *Edge* or do I get some *Edges* for free?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This has changed as the rules have been refined over the editions.

### Test Drive v6 (*Savage Worlds Explorer's Edition* era)

Edges are optional at character creation, and can be bought later when you've earned enough experience points for an Advance. However, at character creation you have the option of taking Hindrances, which give you either one or two points (which the Test Drive confusingly calls "advances": a related but different concept in the full rules), which you can spend to get Edges (or other things) before play begins.

There's no equivalence between Edges and Hindrances except that it *just so happens* that a Major Hindrance gives you enough points to buy an Edge. ([*Savage Worlds Test Drive v6*](http://www.peginc.com/Downloads/SWEX/TD06.pdf), p. 3, "Edges & Hindrances")

In the *Test Drive* you don't get any free Edges—you need to take some Hindrances to get the points to buy Edges at character creation. In the *Savage Worlds Fantasy Companion*, as well as in several of the Savage Settings, humans are distinguished from the other races by being "flexible", which translates into getting a free Edge at character creation. Otherwise, you start out with no Edges.

### The Wild Hunt (*Savage Worlds Deluxe* era)

As of *Savage Worlds Deluxe* the official stance is that humans get the **flexible** racial attribute whether there are other races in a setting or not, so the new default is that characters get one free Edge to start with. This is explicitly called out in the core rules (under **Races** – **Humans**, p. 21).

The free quick-start edition of Savage Worlds is now an adventure with pre-constructed characters ("The Wild Hunt"), and no character creation rules. Notably, the pregenerated characters are all human and have either two Edges and one more d8 attribute than they normally would have (another use for two Hindrance points) or they have three Edges; this reflects the new standard that humans get one free Edge at character creation regardless of setting.

Giving all humans, even in human-only settings, a free starting Edge is not unbalancing and you can do this without trouble even if you're still using *Savage Worlds Explorer's Edition* or the old *Test Drive* quick-start rules.

Comment: In Savage Worlds humans always get one free Edge. You can purchase additional Edges for two Hindrance points. A Major Hindrance and a Minor Hindrance is worth one point. You may take no more than four points of Hindrances.

Comment: @Timonides That's new; used to be humans only got it as a setting rule. I'll update this.

Answer (score 7):

In stock SW (Explorer's Edition), humans get one free Edge, kinda like humans getting a free feat in D&D.  Other than that you have to take Hindrances.  (Hindrances get you points that can be spent on other things too, but Edges are one of those things.)